# Why JSON import to a table shows all null values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL Server 2016 dev

I have tried to import JSON data into a SQL Server in-memory table before loading it to a physical table

```
DECLARE @JSON varchar(max)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\somedatafolder\olympic-winners-large.json', SINGLE_CLOB) Q

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON)
```

When the query executes, the result is shown as

[image]

Then I have load that data to an in-memory table

```
DECLARE @JSON varchar(max)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\somedatafolder\olympic-winners-large.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Q

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) 
WITH ([Athlete] varchar(255),
      [Age] varchar(255),
      [Country] varchar(255)) AS sample1
```

After execution of the query it shown the correct number of rows were imported (8618) but all rows shown `NULL` value

[image]

I would like to know why this happened and how do I fix this?

Comment: please paste the sample data in plain text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is case sensitive.  Notice I changed the column names to lowercase

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max)
SELECT @JSON=BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\somedatafolder\olympic-winners-large.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Q
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) 
WITH(  [athlete] varchar(255),
       [age] varchar(255),
       [country] varchar(255) ) as sample1
```

Comment: your answer worked but before i mark it as the answer and mark the question as answered, is there away to make the operation ignore case, so that data import would not require to create tables with lower cases column names?

Comment: Rather than select * ....  you could select Age = age

Comment: Always happy to help